# Kinetic kudu image does not appear in Multipass find

Tags: ventura

When I run `multipass launch kinetic --name primary --cpus 2 --mem 2G --disk 30G` it throws

```
warning: "--mem" long option will be deprecated in favour of "--memory" in a future release.Please update any scripts, etc.
launch failed: 'kinetic' is not a supported alias. Please use `multipass find` for supported image aliases.
```

Ignoring the "`--mem`" is deprecated warning, it says to use `multipass find` to list the available images, so I did.
here is the output:

```
$ multipass find
Image                       Aliases           Version          Description
snapcraft:core18            18.04             20201111         Snapcraft builder for Core 18
snapcraft:core20            20.04             20210921         Snapcraft builder for Core 20
snapcraft:core22            22.04             20220426         Snapcraft builder for Core 22
18.04                       bionic            20221207         Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
20.04                       focal             20221213         Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
22.04                       jammy,lts         20221214         Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
anbox-cloud-appliance                         latest           Anbox Cloud Appliance
charm-dev                                     latest           A development and testing environment for charmers
docker                                        latest           A Docker environment with Portainer and related tools
jellyfin                                      latest           Jellyfin is a Free Software Media System that puts you in control of managing and streaming your media.
minikube
```

There was no plain cloud image listed with the version I'm looking for.
I tried using the [kinetic image](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/kinetic/current/kinetic-server-cloudimg-amd64.img) URL but it kept throwing me this error:
`launch failed: http and file based images are not supported`

Is there any way to fix this? The host is macOS 13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay they have fixed this issue in the newer update. now i'm getting:

```
% multipass find  
Image                       Aliases           Version          Description
snapcraft:core18            18.04             20201111         Snapcraft builder for Core 18
snapcraft:core20            20.04             20210921         Snapcraft builder for Core 20
snapcraft:core22            22.04             20220426         Snapcraft builder for Core 22
18.04                       bionic            20230112         Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
20.04                       focal             20230117         Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
22.04                       jammy,lts         20230107         Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
22.10                       kinetic           20230112         Ubuntu 22.10
anbox-cloud-appliance                         latest           Anbox Cloud Appliance
charm-dev                                     latest           A development and testing environment for charmers
docker                                        latest           A Docker environment with Portainer and related tools
jellyfin                                      latest           Jellyfin is a Free Software Media System that puts you in control of managing and streaming your media.
minikube
```